# Point symbols auto-scaling in map with QGIS 3.2

Tags: qgis-3, point, symbology, scale, map-drawing

My point symbols are auto scaling when zooming in and out.
I have seen users ask how to do this and the answer seems to be changing the size measurement to map units, but I am in millimeters and it is still auto scaling no matter what I change the unit type to.
[image]

[image]

Might be hard to see but using the road for scale the symbol increased in size as the scale decreased. From what I can find, this is supposed to only happen when using map units, though I am fairly new to QGIS and could be wrong. Why is this happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In QGIS 3.6, there is an option for "meters at scale". It will stick its size into the current projection (I recommend to convert it to UTM projection).

[image: Picture 1]

[image: Picture 2]

Comment: Thank you so much. I felt starting to feel like I was taking crazy pills